# How do I get $_POST in wordpress plugin after using add_filter('rewrite_rules_array')

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm hoping this is super easy. It's late and I'm tired.

```
add_filter('do_parse_request', array($this, 'intercept_wp_router'), 1, 3);
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', array($this, 'rewrite_rules'));
add_filter('query_vars', array($this, 'query_vars'));
add_action('wp_loaded', array($this, 'flush_rewrites'));
add_action('parse_request', array($this, 'v1_api'), 1, 3);
```

I found an example from a blog where he used this combination of rules in the constructor of an object for a plugin.php file. I am able to hit the page at the rewritten url HOWEVER my problem is that I can't seem to access anything from the $_POST variable

during the rewrite, I get the `$wp->query_vars` just fine, but there's no POST data in there.

What am I missing? where's my HTTP POST data?

Comment: Is this an internal or an external rewrite? The latter would be followed by the browser by making a GET request, so in that case you lose your POST data. (Unless you use the specific HTTP status code that instructs the client to make the request again using the same method. But for larger uploads you usually don’t want that either.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use action hook like

```
add_action('init','function_name');
function function_name(){
 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($_POST);
}
```